# What was the wrestling of Yaakov and "a man" about?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, vayishlach

> וַיִּוָּתֵר יַעֲקֹב לְבַדּוֹ וַיֵּאָבֵק אִישׁ עִמּוֹ עַד עֲלוֹת הַשָּׁחַר׃
>   Jacob was left alone. And a man wrestled with him until the break of dawn. ([Gen 32.25](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.32.25?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))

- What was that "man's" purpose or goal of that wrestling? What did he try to do to Yaakov - harm him, kill him, just for fun?
- If he was an angel, how is any harm to Yaakov possible without G-d's command? Or was it G-d's mission?
- Why did he choose wrestling and not fighting with swords, for example?

Comment: VTC as too broad.

Comment: @DonielF This is interesting, as I could ask 3 different questions, but the problem with the answers is that no one will cover other aspects. This Rabbi only addresses this issue, another Rabbi - a different one but disregards the first, etc. To [try to] find the truth - an answer that covers all possible angles of the question is needed.

Comment: @AlBerko You have these questions because you read the story literally. If you understand it as a dream, as Rambam suggest, all questions are removed. Rambam did answer all three, in a sense.

Comment: @TurkHill Even if they wrestled in his dream they still wrestled and the questions stand, I think. You keep saying "don't take it literally" but don't really offer an alternative. Just saying it's not physical but something else requires that something else defined even better than physical.

Comment: @AlBerko the wrestling could have been a dream and it might have had an effect on Jocob on the following day. I think the alternative is good. I also think this answers the question in some regards. We may never know why Jacob dreamed this dream or what exactly occurred. Anything we say will be speculation. Perhaps Jacob thought of wrestling with Esau, rather than using swords or armies and had a dream about wrestling with a man. In the dream he wins and so feels satisfied and attempts absolution.

Comment: [Jacob] said to him, 'Are you a thief or a rogue(17) that you are afraid of the morning? ' He replied: 'I am an angel, and from the day that I was created my time to sing praises [to the Lord] had not come until now'.

Comment: @kouty it could mean that the man is called angel due to his pious life.  He could be speaking poetically about the praises or it could mean that he does the will of G-d. You may see my answer below for context.

Answer (score 1):

Genesis 32:23-33 tells the strange incident of Jacob wrestling with an angel. Expecting to encounter Esau the following day, he reportedly wrestled with a man until daybreak. During the battle, Jacob’s thigh is injured.

Maimonides felt that G-d does not rely on helpers or angels to do His will. Instead, he equates angels with the natural forces that do G-d’s will such as the wind, snow, and rain. In his Guide of the Perplexed 3: 42, Rambam writes that the events in Genesis 32:23-33 did not happen; “it was entirely a prophetic vision.”

Some see the story as a dream. After returning from twenty years of exile Jacob may have felt uneasy and feared for his life. His fears accompanied him in his sleep. An MA in psychology also explains why Jacob limped upon awakening. It is possible that the dream impacted him due to its traumatic nature.

---

If we take the story literaly, however, it could be that the term angel refers to good people. The man might have wanted to test Jacob's strength if he was working for Esau or he may have wanted to tire Jacob. They might have agreed to refrain from using swords since the man did not want to kill him, as can be seen when he hurt Jacob's thigh.

To answer your second question, G-d tested Jacob with a mission. But if Jacob indeed fought with a supernatural human, how did he win?

Answer (score 1):

[Rabbi Chanoch](https://mizrachi.org/speaker/rabbi-chanoch-waxman/) Waxman has a piece about this ordeal written in Torah [MiEtzion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1613290063).
His approach is built mostly on Rashbam and expounds upon it.

Yaakov's crossing of the river with his family was a reversal of his determination and preparation to face Esav. At this point in time he chose to flee. When he crossed back to get his utensils, he was faced by the angel who was sent to teach him to face his fear of Esav.